# Как перевести "said", поддерживая gender neutrality?

Tags: поддержка, локализация, термины

Например, как «cказали» (as in: «вы сказали»), вместо «сказал» (мужской род).

[Кодекс поведения Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) этого не требует в явной форме. Хотя слова о дискриминации по различным признакам там есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Выбранный вариант*.

"also said" -- «также cказали»

---

*Остальные варианты*.

- "also said" - «было сказано». Например, "{{ username }} also said", "было сказано {{ username }}".
- "also said" -- «также cказал».
- Нужно наконец добавить поле "пол" в профиль. Кроме глаголов в некоторых языках это решает проблемы с местоимениями в личном общении в практически всех языках. А уже в зависимости от значения поля — или сказал/сказала/сказал(а), или сказал/сказала/сказало. Форма сказали в значении "сказало лицо неизвестного пола" в русском языке отсутствует, не надо напрямую дублировать костыли из английского языка. В русском языке, если приспичит проявлять нейтральность, всё-таки принято писать сказал(а). И да, это выглядит отвратительно.

Comment: «{{ username }} также сказали» — по-моему, очень плохо звучит, совершенно не по-русски. даже канцелярское «сказал(-а)» — значительно лучше.